# kwargs and args with if statements

Tags: function, if-statement, args, keyword-argument

I am wanting to create a function with a variabele lenght of arguments after the second argument using either args or kwargs.
The aim of the function is to exclude newly created lists from a main lis I tried as follows:

```
def next_row_list1(list_a, list_b, *args):
non_matches = []
for i in list_a:
    if i not in list_b:
        if args:
            if i not in args:

                non_matches.append(i)
return non_matches
new_row_list1 = next_row_list1(row_list, ID01, ID02, ID03)
```

However, the output is a list containing only the newly created lists and not the original list minus the newly created ones.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to incorporate the args and kwargs correctly?

Comment: looks like there is a typo. you have defined the function as  "next_row_list1" but you are calling  "next_row_list()"

Comment: Can you provide a sample example of what the lists/arguments look like and what is your expected output?

Comment: an exemplary list:31074,
51789,74722,958473. This one should be detached from a bigger list (after having been grouped). What should remain is the bigger list (same format) of which new list have to be detached untill nothing is left...